# Python2: access nested list using a list of indices

Tags: python, nested-lists

how do I access an element of a nested list with another list which contains the indices?

e.g:

```
# this is the variable containing the indices
a = [0, 1]

b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

in reality, these lists are filled with elements of self defined classes and the list containing the "coordinates" (a) has more than 2 elements.

Is there any possibility to access b[0][1] automatically? Previously, I used this code:

```
c = deepcopy(b)
for el in a:
    c = c[el]
```

but since b is pretty big, I'd love to get rid of that deepcopy without manipulating b in reality.

I am happy about any suggestions :)

Thanks!

Comment: I sense an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What's your goal with this code?

Comment: I have a nested list `b`, whose elements i would like to acces using the indices in the list `a`. The second code fragment just shows what I've used so far. If you have any suggestions, please tell me :)

Comment: Really, the correct way to do it is `b[a[0]][a[1]]` there is no pretty way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just toss it in a function. That will keep it scoped so you don't overwrite the original value

```
def nested_getitem(container, idxs):
    haystack = container
    for idx in idxs:
        haystack = haystack[idx]
    return haystack
```

DEMO:

```
>>> a = [0, 1]
>>> b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> nested_getitem(b, a)
2
```

You could probably do this with a `functools.reduce` as well, if you were insane.

```
import functools
import operator

def nested_getitem(container, idxs):
    return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, idxs, container)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for giving out the elements, but what if i wanted to manipulate the item? e.g. nested_getitem(b,a) = 0.

Comment: @user3692467 in which case why are you trying to deepcopy in the example in your question???